# Haskell Increment by One

Tags: haskell

Trying to create a Haskell program that increments every number in a list by one.

```
module Add1List where
add1_list_comp :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
add1_list_comp [x] = [x + 1| x <- [x]]
```

It works when I call this `add1_list_comp [3]` ... it gives me `[4]`

But when I do `add1_list_comp [3, 4, 5]` ... it throws me an error saying

> "non-exhaustive patterns in function add1_list_comp"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Awesome resource](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) for learning Haskell.

Comment: Rewriting list comprehensions in terms of `map`, `concat`, etc often makes the code much clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
add1_list_comp = map succ
```

that simple

or, in your way

```
add1_list_comp xs = [x + 1| x <- xs]
```

the problem with your code is that

```
add1_list_comp [x]
```

does pattern match on list with single item, that's why it fails on list with several items.

Comment: This is a 'gimme teh codez answer' (well, okay, you edited so not so much anymore) ... I think it would be more beneficial for both the OP and future SO users if the answer went into more detail about what's going on in this solution.  Remember, even though it may be totally trivial for you, the OP is clearly a beginner and may need many 'obvious' things explicitly pointed out and explained.

Comment: Yes! I am def a begginer! Thank you for the help though. Obvious fix though lol

Comment: Actually list operations are described in so much places so I don't see a point to reinvent the wheel. If you're asking question - somebody gives an answer. That how it works im my opinion. If OP doesn't understand what lists are and what operations on a list are available - it's not subject of copypasting whole manual.

Comment: @jdevelop, in a question as simple as this I agree.  For slightly more complex but still beginner answers, I have settled on giving them a hint to help them with their immediate difficulty, but still leaving more work to do.  That will help them internalize the answer and build it into their conceptual framework.

Answer (score 6):

I see that the question has been answered, but perhaps I can explain a bit more.
The argument of a function is pattern matched, and the general rules are

```
(x:xs)
```

x is the head of the list and xs is the tail of the list, and potentially empty list

```
[]
```

empty list

```
[x] or (x:[])
```

are the same which is a list with only one variable

and a name with no constructor such as "[]", ":", "(,)" around can match anything, so if you want to match a special case, you should put the special case in front of the general pattern.

```
 length [] = 0
 length [x] = 1
 length (x : xs) = 1 + length xs
```

BTW, generally speaking, there will always be a higher order function when you want to do something with a list. for your case

```
 add1 xs = map (+1) xs
```

is nicer and it took advantage of the built in library, and you can also do a point free version of it

```
 add1 = map (+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well actually since the topic states "Increment by One" without defining what type is going to be incremented by one, just for the sake of a visitor ended up here lets give a solution which would increment any functor by one, which of course includes the list type. So;

List functor

```
*Main> fmap (+1) [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

Maybe functor (`id` applies to `Nothing`)

```
*Main> fmap (+1) (Just 1)
Just 2
```

Either functor  (`id` applies to `Left _`)

```
*Main> fmap (+1) (Right 2)
Right 3
```

IO functor

```
*Main> fmap ((+1) . read) getLine
2017
2018
```